# Take the LSB of each int in an array and combine them to create a byte

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

So right now i have this

```
unsigned char getlsbs(unsigned char *p){
    int r;
    unsigned char newByte, temp;
    newByte = 0;

    for(r = 0; r < 8; r++){
            temp = p[r];
            temp &= -temp; // Gets the LSB of p[r]
            ((newByte & (1 << r)) >> r) |= temp; //This line does not work
    }
    return newByte;
}
```

for the line that doesn't work I am trying to set the rth int of newByte into the LSD so I can turn 00000000 into something like 10100001 any help would be greatly apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way to accumulate bits into a target is to left shift in-place the previous value left, then OR in the new bit: `newByte = (newByte << 1) | (temp & 0x01)`   In the above code, the left hand side of the line that says, "This line does not work" does not appear to be a valid target for an assignment operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to an expression. To simplify the problem: `a + 1 = b` doesn't work. Rewrite that as `a = b - 1` instead.

I would just do:

```
for(r = 0; r < 8; r++){
    newByte |= (p[r] & 1) >> r;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that kind of works.  I guess i should have said p is an array of 8 ints that i have already assigned the LSB. So now i have to take the LSBs of each int and combine them to make the newByte which should equal the old byte.  I slightly changed it to newByte |= (p[r] & temp) >> r; but that still doesn't change it all correctly

Comment: Ah I see. `a & -a` returns the **first set bit**, while `a & 1` returns the **least significant bit**. Please update that in your question. But then I don't really get what you would expect as output.

Comment: @Clark Can you update the question, as it's using the wrong terminology, and the code doesn't match what you're saying here. According to your comment, the solution is just simply `newByte |= p[r];`